# how to move contacts en mass from one iCloud account to another

Tags: icloud, contacts, contacts.app

I need to have two iCloud accounts, one for work and one for play/personal. Is there an easy way to move all contacts from one iCloud account to another via iCloud.com. For example, if I have 400 contacts in my personal iCloud account and none in my work iCloud account, how would I lift them from the personal account to the work account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mac Contacts..

File menu > Export > Contacts Archive

then

File Menu > Import

---

Or from iCloud…

Prefs 'cog'
Select All
Export vCard - which will save a 'batch' vCard to your default DL location [then, irritatingly, immediately try to import it to your Mac Contacts list, so hit Cancel]

Swap iCloud accounts, then import vCard

Comment: And how about from iCloud.com?

Comment: added iCloud method